# Ubuntu Hotspot - Need IP range same as other LAN devices

Tags: ubuntu, hotspot, wireless-hotspot

There are multiple ubuntu systems connected in LAN. All have IP range 192.168.0.2, 192.168.0.3, 192.168.0.4 etc

When any system starts a hotspot service, it starts successfully and smart phone devices can be connected successfully so any hotspot.

But their IP range is 10.42.0.2, 10.42.0.8, 10.42.0.23 etc

I need to create them same as LAN IP range i.e. 192.168.0.x

Please help.

Thank You

Comment: What is the Actual Ip of the hotspot?

Comment: When devices are getting connected to hotspot, they are getting these IPs and when I am checking ubuntu system's IP in connection information, it is also showing 10.42.0.x but when I stop hotspot, ubuntu system's IP is again 192.168.0.x

Comment: The hotspot is probably changing the Ip range to avoid any conflict with the lans ip ranges. So the hotspot could possibly have the ip range of the 10.42.0.2 and so on. You would need to modify the hotspot settings if you were wanting the same but then again be careful of ip collisions.

Comment: Ok but I am not getting any setting regarding hotspot IP range setting. Can you please tell me where I can define the range of Hotspot IPs?